# Primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$: necessary and sufficient condition not in terms of a "modulo equation"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

For particular cases ($n=1,2,3$) we can find an "elementary" necessary and sufficient condition, i.e.

$$p = x^2 + y^2 \Leftrightarrow p \equiv 1 \mod 4$$
$$p = x^2 + 2y^2 \Leftrightarrow p \equiv 1,3 \mod 8$$
$$p = x^2 + 3y^2 \Leftrightarrow p =3 \textrm{ or  } p \equiv 1 \mod 3$$

However, the general case, as proven in David Cox's book, gives a polynomial expression:

[image]

How can I argue that it is **impossible** to find a more "elementary" modulo expression?

Comment: @fretty: Dear fretty, I'm not sure that your comment is addressing the question, but perhaps I've misunderstood your point.  It is certainly true that in general there is no congruence condition on $p$ (modulo $4n$ or any other modulus) which determines whether it can be written in the form $x^2 + n y^2$.    Regards,

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood the question...comment deleted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not easy to prove; it relies on class field theory.

This [MO question and its answers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/11688/2874) give an explanation.  The point is that (for all but finitely many $p$), we can write $p = x^2 + n y^2$ iff $p$ splits in the Hilbert Class Field of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-n})$,
and so we get a congruence condition iff the HCF is abelian over $\mathbb Q$.

This fails e.g. for $n = 23$.  (In this case the polynomials $f_{23}(x)$ can be taken to be $x^3 - x - 1$, and the HCF of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-23})$ is the $S_3$ extension of $\mathbb Q$ obtained as the splitting field of this polynomial.) 
In this case, one has the following statement: we can write an odd prime $p$,
different from $23$, in the form $x^2 + 23 y^2$ iff the coefficient of 
$q^p$ in $q \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^n)(q-q^{23 n})$ equals $2$. (It is always either $-1,0,$ or $2$.)

Answer (score 3):

Got me. I think you can prove impossibility by clever use of Chebotarev density, especially Theorem 9.12 on page 188. The density of primes represented by a (positive) form is some $1/k.$ If these were collected in an arithmetic progression, except for a few that divide the discriminant, the progression would need to be $k n + b.$ And I think you can rule that out, at least by experimenting with any specific example; i encourage you to experiment with this, in the examples below.

Let me give you some examples to chew on.

For odd primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$ there is an expression in integers $p = u^2 + 27 v^2 $ if and only if $2$ is a cube $\pmod p.$ The others are represented by $4 u^2 \pm 2 u v + 7 v^2.$

For odd primes other than $3$ itself with $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$ there is an expression in integers $p = u^2 + u v + 61 v^2 $ if and only if $3$ is a cube $\pmod p.$ The others are represented by $7 u^2 \pm  3 u v + 9 v^2.$

For odd primes other than $23$ with $(p | 23) = 1$ there is an expression in integers $p = u^2 + 23 v^2 $ if and only there are three distinct roots to $ x^3 - x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p.$  The others are represented by $3 u^2 \pm  2 u v + 8 v^2.$

For odd primes other than $31$ with $(p | 31) = 1$ there is an expression in integers $p = u^2 + 31 v^2 $ if and only there are three distinct roots to $ x^3 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p.$  The others are represented by $5 u^2 \pm  4 u v + 7 v^2.$