# Factorization of $x^3-x-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, quadratic-forms, cubics

Factoring quadratic polynomials over finite fields can easily be done by determining if the discriminant is a quadratic residue modulo characteristic in question, and if so, apply the quadratic formula to obtain a solution in that finite field. Otherwise, the quadratic remains irreducible over that field. This characterizes behaviors of quadratic polynomials factoring over finite fields.

What about cubic polynomials, particularly those whose Galois group is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_3$?

For example, I want to determine the factoring behavior of $f(x)=x^3-x-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. I know that $f$ is the equation for the Hilbert Class Field of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$.

Hence, I would assume that for all primes which can be represented as $p = 23x^2+y^2$ for integers $x,y$, then $f$ will decompose into linear factors over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Hence, the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is itself.

In the case that $-23$ is a quadratic non-residue $\pmod p$, then $f$ decomposes into one linear factor and one quadratic factor over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Hence, $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Lastly, if $-23$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod p$, but $p\neq 23x^2+y^2$ for integers $x, y$, then $f$ should be irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, so the splitting field becomes $\mathbb{F}_{p^3}$.

I've made some observations here, but how would I go about proving them? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: In characteristics other than $2,3$ you can always brute force your way using the cubic formula and then handle the small cases directly just as in the quadratic case with $2$ (though if you intend to generalize the arbitrary degree polynomials this obviously won't work)

Comment: Over a finite field all Galois groups are cyclic. Therefore irreducibility of a cubic implies that its discriminant must be a square (otherwise the Galois group would be $S_3$ which is impossible). Also, if $p=23x^2+y^2$ then $-23=(y/x)^2$ in $\Bbb{F}_p$, and $-23$ is a quadratic residue. But this doesn't really take us towards the characterization of totally split case. Chebotarev says that it happens for one sixth of the primes (asymptotically). But, as the Galois group over $\Bbb{Q}$ is all of $S_3$, hence non-abelian, we cannot use residue classes to describe those primes.

Comment: (cont'd) quadratic forms do work in those cases, but I never understood why. I guess the explanation comes from understanding the ideal class group of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$ and the connection between the ideal classes and quadratic forms sharing the same discriminant, but I never understood that connection. All I can guess is that because this is not an $h=1$ case, there will also be other quadratic forms that you need to consider.

Comment: @T. Rex.-I think you have to edit something: $23=23\cdot1^1+0^2$ but $x^3-x-1=(x+13)^2(x+20)$ over $\mathbb F_{23}$ i. e. $f(x)$ does not decompose into linear factors. Regards.

Comment: @T. Rex.-I wanted just to say that the mentioned linear factors are not necessarily distinct. For example, your $f(x)=(x-5)^3$ over $\mathbb F_{17}$ obviously decompose into linear factors too but all of the three equal.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen   other than the Cox book, specific calculations are done in http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf   with an expanded discussion in http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Spearman_Williams_1992.pdf   There is a similar article for $h(-D) = 4$  by Liu and Williams  in Tamkang   https://journals.math.tku.edu.tw/index.php/TKJM/article/view/4461

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen   Williams and Spearman have a follow-up, two pages  only, https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/233.pdf    My interest comes from my 2010 question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12486/integers-not-represented-by-2-x2-x-y-3-y2-z3-z

Comment: Thanks @WillJagy. Spearman & Williams first lost me at the starting gate as I had never heard of Stickelberger's parity theorem (from 1897). That hurdle turned out to be easy. I simply calculated that the discriminant of $(x-c)(x^2+ax+b)$ is $(a^2-4b)(b+ac+c^2)^2$. Proving that the discriminant of a product of a linear and  quadratic is a square if and only if the discriminant of the quadratic factor is a square. It's a bit embarrassing to find holes like this in my understanding, but at least I can now proceed :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  glad you like them. I got some use out of some of the theorems, I figured you could actually go through the proofs as well.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the references! I find them quite helpful. I didn't know that the cases for each individual class number are treated separately. These complete the case for cubic polynomials: if they do not correspond to a subfield of a cyclotomic field, then they are a subfield of some quadratic Hilbert Class Field. Hopefully this is right.

Comment: I think the following threads are relevant to this: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/624374/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2688853/11619).